# Animate two divs left side

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want two divs to animate left side.

```
div1 - contains text - float left
div2 - contains icons - float left
```

Once i click on div1 it should move left with icons.

blue boxes are moving right to left but the text follow us is on left side.
What I want is Follow us text should be on right side and once i click on it then it should move left like blue boxes moves.

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="socialtext">Follow us</div>
    <div class="socailicons">
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.socialtext').click(function () {
        $('.socailicons').toggle("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#footer{
            width: 300px;
            border: 1px solid #FF0000;
            height: 35px;
        }
        .socialtext{
            width: 100px;
            float:left;
        }
        .socailicons{
            width: auto;
            display:none;
            float:left;
        }
        .icon{
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0769AD;
            float:left;
            margin: 10px;
        }
```

I wants the "Follow us" text, on the right side of the box, and when clicked it gets pushed to the left with the icons. Icons will be hidden initially and it will be shown on click on "follow us" text.

Comment: Please check my try on 

http://jsfiddle.net/E8yWJ/

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I think he wants the "Follow us" text, on the right side of the box, and when clicked it gets pushed to the left with the icons.

Comment: @PriyankGoswami please update your question, making that statement clearer and actually showing the code here.  It's really unclear.

Comment: you can check fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/E8yWJ/ created by me in comment

Comment: you could put that in the question???

Comment: @NoLiver92 Please check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `div` is added to wrap `socialtext` and `socailicons`, so that they can be moved together easily.

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="socialtext">Follow us</div>
    <div class="socailicons">
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`float: left;` is changed to `display: inline;`, so that the elements can be more dynamic.

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;    /* hide the div that is out of the border */
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    right: -200px;    /* move it to the right so that 
                        .socialicons is out of the border */
}
.socialtext {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.socailicons {
    display: inline;
}
.icon {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0769AD;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Use `.animate()` to move it instead.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isShown = false;
    $('.socialtext').click(function() {
        // toggle moving left and right
        var offset = isShown? "-=200px": "+=200px";
        isShown = !isShown;
        $('#wrapper').animate({"right": offset}, 1000);
    });
});
```